# Distinct count on multiple unrelated columns

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I've a dataset where from I want distinct count of more than one column and get the result in one single select, how to go about it?

Example:

Table:

```
|Col_A|Col_B|
|a    |c    |
|a    |d    |
|b    |c    |
|b    |d    |
|b    |c    |
```

I want like this (with the use of a single select query) -

```
|Col_A|Count_of_A|Col_B|Count_of_B|
|a    |2         |c    |3         |
|b    |3         |d    |2         |
```

How to do this? Given that, data is unknown every-time and hence, we cannot use where or case statements for specific use-case.

Ideally this is a Spark-Streaming problem, where I want to do this operation on a Spark-streaming dataframe every time new data comes in from Kafka.

Comment: The output table you're asking for as you show it isn't going to make sense. Your example assumes that there's an equal number of distinct  values in each column. But that may not be true. What would an example output table look like in that case, for example, if column B had values c, d, and e? In addition, there is no logical relationship between all of the attributes of each row in that table. All of the information, in any form, is not likely obtainable with a single select. Maybe with a single query if you're willing to accept an output with columns: column name, column value, count.

Comment: Exactly, that is where I'm getting stuck to write this query. I thought of writing that in the question, for unequal uniques, maybe we can append nulls at the end. This is a requirement and I'm literally clueless.

Comment: Why is that table output format a requirement?

Comment: I've to create a histogram in the UI which will render the distinct values and count of each column. In Spark-Streaming, doing multiple queries will increase operation cost and also, when a user clicks on EDA the histogram should crop up immediately rather than running multiple queries in the meantime. Hence, one table would solve the purpose, but making it is difficult.

Comment: So the table format isn't required, but you are trying to get SQL, in a single query, to provide you the format most convenient for your historgram. Whatever query you come up with, it would necessarily be a compound query, so you're going to end up with multiple queries whether you do them separately or embedded in a single compound query if you're trying to get SQL to generate the data in a form most convenient for your histogram. Alternatively, in your program, you could just query the whole table and compute your histogram using a dictionary or associative array structure.